# If greater equal than - variable is a date value (from date format) - PHP

Tags: php, date, operators

This is my code:

```
$interval->format('%d');

if ($interval >= '1') {
$message = "welcome back!";
}
else
{
    $message = "meh";
}
```

This is not working because $interval is a date format.

I tried to convert it using:

```
$interval = strval($interval);
```

I am tryning to convert $interval to a number or string so that I can do the comparison - becaue right now, the if then else returns welcome back always.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What exactly is it that you are attempting to check/test? In other words, what are you attempting to achieve or what is the goal of this code?

Comment: `$interval` is a DateTime object or what?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to convert it to a number so that I can do the comparison - becaue right now, the if then else returns welcome back always.

Comment: @CodyRaspien Right now you don't do anything with your formatting call. So you either want to use the format call inside the if statement or first assign it to a variable. Also you probably want to format the day without leading zero, e.g. `if($interval->format('%j') >= 1)`

Comment: `$days = $interval->format('%a');` and then `if ($days >= 1) {`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
if($interval->format('%d') >= 1)
```